# How to select duplicate value from a list in C# based on condition?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, duplicates, keyvaluepair

I have a list with date and Fileno as values. I need to find the duplicate date and based on that find the highest Fileno.Then add that keyvalue pair and the distinct pair to the final list. The result should be as shown below.I am able to get the duplicate date but how to compare the duplicate dates and find the highest fileno?

```
Key  Date       Fileno
 1  10/8/1980   1234
 2  10/8/1980   1345
 3  8/6/1970    4567
```

Result

```
 2  10/8/1980   1345
 3  8/6/1970    4567
```

Code

```
var list = new List<valuepair>();
list.Add(new valuepair {no=key,comdate=date,filnum=fileno})
Var dup= list.GroupBy(x => comdate.Value).Where(x => comdate.Count() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(
        i => i.Date,
        (key, group) => group.Single(x => x.Fileno == group.Max(y => y.Fileno)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there, except the code you've posted is not compilable (!). You just need to take the element with the highest "filnum" from each group:

```
var list = new List<valuepair>();
list.Add(new valuepair { no=1, comdate="10/8/1980", filnum=1234 });
list.Add(new valuepair { no=2, comdate="10/8/1980", filnum=1345 });
list.Add(new valuepair { no=3, comdate="8/6/1970", filnum=4567 });

var listWithoutDuplicates = list.GroupBy(x => x.comdate)
    // For each group (in which items have identical dates) take only
    // the one with the highest "filnum"
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.filnum).First())
    .ToList();
```